# Is there a way to detect url changes with Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I made a site phishing searcher using Python. Here is the code that i use

```
output = []
for i in range (100):
    for subdomain_count in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
        webtypo = random.choice(typo) + '.odoo.com'
        http = random.choice(HTTP)
        data = random.sample(web, k=subdomain_count) + [webtypo]
        delims = (random.choices(delimiters, k=subdomain_count)
        address = ''.join([a+b for a, b in zip(data, delims)])
        weburl = http + address
        output.append(weburl)

exist=[]

for c in output:
    try:
        request = requests.get(c)
        if request.status_code == 200:
            exist.append(c)
            print('Exist')
        elif request.status_code == 204:
            print('user does not exist')
    except:
        print('Not Exist')
```

When i check the Request URL, the link changes to `https://www.odoo.com/typo?domain=minecraftnet.odoo.com&autodbname=edcandroidbni123&hosting=eu142a`, is there a way to detect in odoo if a link of a website changes it would print out web `does not exist`, but if there's a site that uses the odoo.com tld it would print out `exist`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [`response.url`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.url) parameter to get the final URL after any redirects.

```py
    response = requests.get(c)
    final_url = response.url
```

Note this only handles 3xx redirects, not javascript redirects. Requests will never execute javascript.

Comment: How does that work? since the url changes doesn't always output the same link name so i don't this code would work

Comment: If there is a `301` redirect the response changes the `response.history` to get all the responses tried before finding the final URL.